# Decrypting and Copying Contents of Encrypted Text File to MemoryStream

Tags: vb.net, encryption, des, tripledes

I'm trying to copy the encrypted contents of a text file into a memory stream and then decrypt and copy those contents into a new memory stream. When I reach the code where the copy occurs I get a Invalid Data error on debug.

This is the block of code I got:

```
Function DecryptFile(ByVal sInputFilename As String, ByVal sKey As String) As Byte()

    Dim DES As New DESCryptoServiceProvider()

    DES.Key() = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey)
    DES.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey)

    Dim desdecrypt As ICryptoTransform = DES.CreateDecryptor()

    Dim encryptedByteArray() As Byte
    encryptedByteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(sInputFilename)

    Dim encryptedMS As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(encryptedByteArray)
    Dim cryptostreamDecr As New CryptoStream(encryptedMS, desdecrypt, CryptoStreamMode.Read)
    Dim decryptedMS As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()

    cryptostreamDecr.CopyTo(decryptedMS) 'Error occurs here
    cryptostreamDecr.Close()

    Return decryptedMS.ToArray()
End Function
```

I'm following examples I've found scattered around the web and from what I've read, this code should work...

May anyone explain to me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The initialization vector must be the same when encrypting and decrypting and it must be 1/8 of the Provider's BlockSize. You can let the Provider generate the `IV`, but use the same in both operations. The `Provider.Key` should be derived and salted: see the [Rfc2898DeriveBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes) class. -- DES is kind of deprecated. Use TripleDES or AES Managed (RijndaelManaged).

Comment: Oh crap... In that case, I've got to store the IV of the encryption somewhere? Considering that the point of using a memorystream is to only have the encrypted file and get the decrypted contents on runtime, how should I store the IV key without having an unencrypted file?

Comment: Security storage is tricky :) You can use a symmetric key. Initialize the IV to a sequence of identical bytes (usually, you get the Provider's BlockSize, divide by 8 and generate a IV with that:  `byte[] IV = new byte[BlockSize / 8]`). So you don't actually need to store anything, but you *lose something* at the same time. Or use an algorithm that doesn't require an initialization vector. It depends on what kind of security you want to apply and apply to what. Plain text is not the same as an image, for example.

Comment: Ok, I need some advice here. When I encrypted the text file, I used the encryption method with a random generated IV. This IV is generated based on a randomly generated secret key. Would be it viable to run the encryption procedure to store the generated secret key, discard that procedure and then run the decryption procedure with that same key?

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example to encrypt/decrypt a string and a file using a Key without explicitly providing an Initialization Vector (so yo don't need to store and retrieve it to decrypt encrypted data).

The Encryption provider I'm using here is [TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.tripledescryptoserviceprovider).
If you need to use a DES provider, it's exactly the same thing, you just need to change `TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider` to [DESCryptoServiceProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.descryptoserviceprovider).
But, as you can read in the Docs, better move to the [AesCryptoServiceProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aescryptoserviceprovider), if/when possible.

The Initialization Vector (`IV`) is calculated based on the Key specified and it's the same Hashed value if the Key to Decrypt the data is the same as the Key used to Encrypt it.

In this case, you lose some security, but you don't need to store either the Key or the `IV` (if the Key is provided by a User, who's responsible for protecting the Key).

The [Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.mode) is left to its default: `CipherMode.CBC`.
The [Padding Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.padding) to its default: `PaddingMode.PKCS7`.

---

Encrypt and decrypt a sting to and from a Base64String:

```
Dim enc3Des As New TripleDesEncryptor("MyFancyKey")

Dim inputString = "Some fancy string to be encoded to a Base64 string"
Dim encodedB64 = enc3Des.EncryptStringToBase64(inputString)
Dim decoded64 = enc3Des.DecryptBase64String(encoded64)
```

To encrypt a file, provide the path to the Source file, then save the bytes returned by the Encryption method to a destination file:

```
Dim enc3Des As New TripleDesEncryptor("MyFancyKey")

Dim plainTextFilePath = [Source file Path]
Dim encryptedFilePath = [Encrypted file Path]

Dim encodedBytes = enc3Des.EncryptFile(plainTextFilePath)
File.WriteAllBytes(encryptedFilePath, encodedBytes)
```

You can of course decrypt the File when required, using the same Key:

```
Dim encryptedFilePath = [Encrypted file Path]
Dim decryptedFilePath = [Decrypted file Path]

Dim enc3Des2 As New TripleDesEncryptor("MyFancyKey")

Dim decodedBytes = enc3Des2.DecryptFile(encryptedFilePath)
File.WriteAllBytes(decryptedFilePath, decodedBytes)
```

The `TripleDesEncryptor` helper class:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.Text

Public NotInheritable Class TripleDesEncryptor

    Private tripleDesProvider As New TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider()

    Sub New(key As String)
        tripleDesProvider.Key = GetKeyHash(key, tripleDesProvider.LegalKeySizes(0).MaxSize \ 8)
        tripleDesProvider.IV = GetKeyHash(key, tripleDesProvider.LegalBlockSizes(0).MaxSize \ 8)
    End Sub

    Public Function EncryptStringToBase64(inputString As String) As String
        Dim dataBytes As Byte() = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(inputString)
        Return Convert.ToBase64String(Encrypt(dataBytes))
    End Function

    Public Function EncryptFile(fileName As String) As Byte()
        Dim dataBytes As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName)
        Return Encrypt(dataBytes)
    End Function

    Private Function Encrypt(dataBytes As Byte()) As Byte()
        Using ms As New MemoryStream(),
            encStream As New CryptoStream(ms, tripleDesProvider.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write)
            encStream.Write(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.Length)
            encStream.FlushFinalBlock()
            Return ms.ToArray()
        End Using
    End Function

    Public Function DecryptBase64String(base64String As String) As String
        Dim dataBytes As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String)
        Return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(Decrypt(dataBytes))
    End Function

    Public Function DecryptFile(fileName As String) As Byte()
        Dim dataBytes As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName)
        Return Decrypt(dataBytes)
    End Function

    Private Function Decrypt(encryptedData As Byte()) As Byte()
        Using ms As New MemoryStream(),
            decStream As New CryptoStream(ms, tripleDesProvider.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write)
            decStream.Write(encryptedData, 0, encryptedData.Length)
            decStream.FlushFinalBlock()
            Return ms.ToArray()
        End Using
    End Function

    Private Function GetKeyHash(key As String, length As Integer) As Byte()
        Using sha1 = SHA1.Create()
            Dim varHash As Byte() = New Byte(length - 1) {}
            Dim keyBytes As Byte() = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(key)
            Dim hash As Byte() = sha1.ComputeHash(keyBytes).Take(length).ToArray()
            Array.Copy(hash, 0, varHash, 0, hash.Length)
            hash = Nothing
            keyBytes = Nothing
            Return varHash
        End Using
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I should have explained what I'm trying to achieve in the first place.
I have a text file that has over 1000 keywords. The vb.net application will, at some point, read these keywords from the text file to do something with them.
Now, my approach here is to not let prying eyes to edit the text file, changing the key words or even knowing which keywords are on it.
Therefor, what I did was encrypt the keywords and save the encrypted content into a new file and deleted the unencrypted file, so that this way I don't need to care about people checking the encrypted file, because it's just gibberish.

According to Jimi's explanation, posted before, I see now that in order to decrypt the file, I need the same IV I used for encrypting the previous file.

So the only way I see for this to be possible **without having an unencrypted file 'lying around'** is to store the IV secret key within the application's settings, correct?

Comment: This is not an answer, it's a clarification of your intent. If you need to further explain what your question is about, you need to [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64970644/edit), not post non-answers. -- The Key and `IV` matter is explained in the answer I posted. Read again what's in there, see that you only need to store the Key used to encrypt the file. A method to encrypt and decrypt files using only a Key is also shown there.

Comment: You can store the IV on the file - just figured I'd add that here. I usually write the IV/Salt to the beginning of the encrypted content. That way you can just pop it off when you go to decrypt. The IV does not need to be kept secret and can be stored with the encrypted content.