# System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'Bad Data. ' triple DES encryption vb.net ms acces

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, encryption, tripledes

Encryption and Decryption

```
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO



Public Class EncDecCls

    Private tripleDES As New TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider

    'Public Sub New(_KEY As String)
    '    KeyStr = _KEY
    'End Sub

    'Private KeyValue As String
    'Public Property KeyStr() As String
    '    Get
    '        Return KeyValue
    '    End Get
    '    Set(value As String)
    '        KeyValue = value
    '    End Set
    'End Property

    Function Encryption(ByVal datafile As String) As String

        Dim input As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(datafile)

        Dim ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream
        Dim encstream As New CryptoStream(ms, tripleDES.CreateEncryptor(),
                      System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode.Write)

        encstream.Write(input, 0, input.Length)

        encstream.FlushFinalBlock()

        Return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray)

    End Function

    Function Decryption(ByVal encryptedfile As String) As String

        Dim output() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(encryptedfile)

        Dim ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream
        Dim decstream As New CryptoStream(ms, tripleDES.CreateDecryptor(),
                     System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode.Write)

        decstream.Write(output, 0, output.Length)

        decstream.FlushFinalBlock()

        Return System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray)
    End Function
End Class
```

Code to retrieve data from database and decrypt it, then to display on datagridview(DGVSV)

```
Dim cmd1 As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM pwdmgr WHERE username = @uname", conn)
        cmd1.Parameters.Add("@uname", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = x
        conn.Open()
        dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader
        dr.Read()
        DGVSV.Rows.Add(dr.Item("id").ToString,
                           EncryptDecryptFiles.Decryption(dr.Item("email").ToString),
                                EncryptDecryptFiles.Decryption(dr.Item("pwd").ToString))
        
        conn.Close()
```

There are few rows of data to be retrieved and to display it into the datagridview(DGVSV). Everytime when i run this function above it shows this error **System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'Bad Data. '**

Can someone help me on that?

Comment: Where EXACTLY is the exception thrown? What is the data in use at the time?

Comment: the exception is thrown exactly when it is decrypting data from the database. Basically i could encrypt the data but cannot decrypt. The exception was thrown at `FlushFinalBlock()` while decrypting the data from the database

Comment: Where is the part where you set the `Key` and `IV` values of both transforms? Creating encryptors and decryptors this way generates different `Key` and `IV` values each time you call them. See [this](https://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_security/encrypting-important-strings-with-triple-des-and-.net.html) and [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7580/Making-TripleDES-Simple-in-Visual-Basic-NET) for example.

Comment: If you are trying to decrypt, shouldn't you be reading from the `CryptoStream` rather than writing to it? That's a rhetorical question. Yes, you should be reading from it, but you're not. I suggest that you do some research on how to decrypt data because that's not it.

Comment: And... Create the streams in `Using ... End Using` blocks.

Comment: @jmcilhinney It works this way, it depends on what the transforms fill the crypto stream with.

Comment: i followed a youtube tutorial. I don't have prior knowledge on encryption and decryption. Is there any suggestion on how to enrypt and decrypt data in vb.net using windows forms

Comment: `Dim output() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(encryptedfile)

        Dim ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream
                                                                                Using decstream As New CryptoStream(ms, tripleDES.CreateDecryptor(),
                     System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode.Write)
            decstream.Write(output, 0, output.Length)


                                                           decstream.FlushFinalBlock()
                                                           End Using
 `

Is it something like this?

Comment: _I don't have prior knowledge on encryption and decryption._ .. That's why I gave you two articles to read.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64986491/7444103)