# vb.net System.FormatException: 'Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string

Tags: vb.net

i have a problem with a decryption password. System.FormatException: 'Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string.'

Here is my code:

```
   'For decrypt password
    Function Decrypt(str As String) As String
    str = str.Replace(" ", "+")
    Dim DecryptKey As String = "2013;[pnuLIT)WebCodeExpert"
    Dim byKey As Byte() = {}
    Dim IV As Byte() = {18, 52, 86, 120, 144, 171,
     205, 239}
    Dim inputByteArray As Byte() = New Byte(str.Length - 1) {}

    byKey = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(DecryptKey.Substring(0, 8))
    Dim des As New DESCryptoServiceProvider()
    inputByteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(str.Replace(" ", "+"))
    Dim ms As New MemoryStream()
    Dim cs As New CryptoStream(ms, des.CreateDecryptor(byKey, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write)
    cs.Write(inputByteArray, 0, inputByteArray.Length)
    cs.FlushFinalBlock()
    Dim encoding As System.Text.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
    Return encoding.GetString(ms.ToArray())
End Function


'For Encrypt password
Function Encrypt(str As String) As String
    Dim EncrptKey As String = "2013;[pnuLIT)WebCodeExpert"
    Dim byKey As Byte() = {}
    Dim IV As Byte() = {18, 52, 86, 120, 144, 171,
     205, 239}
    byKey = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(EncrptKey.Substring(0, 8))
    Dim des As New DESCryptoServiceProvider()
    Dim inputByteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str)
    Dim ms As New MemoryStream()
    Dim cs As New CryptoStream(ms, des.CreateEncryptor(byKey, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write)
    cs.Write(inputByteArray, 0, inputByteArray.Length)
    cs.FlushFinalBlock()
    Return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray())
End Function
```

In access database:

```
   02FXthNUUZU=
```

Do anyone know what i do bad?

Comment: See the `EncryptStringToBase64()` and `DecryptBase64String()` methods [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64986491/7444103). Read the notes. -- You're using `Encoding.UTF8`, there `Encoding.Unicode` is used. It's the same, what's important is consistency. Also, in that sample code, the Initialization Vector is created from the Key, here' you're using an hard-coded IV. The reason is explained in the notes. It shouldn't really be a byte array inserted directly in the same code, though. -- Don't tamper with the strings.

Comment: @Jimi Thank you very much

Comment: @Jimi I used your code from that link, but when i use my password i have an error: System.FormatException: 'Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string.'

Comment: Do you mean this key: `"2013;[pnuLIT)WebCodeExpert"`? I've just tested it and it works as usual. That class is called like this: `Dim stringToEncrypt = "Some string to encrypt" Dim provider = New TripleDesEncryptor("2013;[pnuLIT)WebCodeExpert") Dim encrypted = provider.EncryptStringToBase64(stringToEncrypt) Dim originalString = provider.DecryptBase64String(encrypted)`. Did you use the code as presented there, as it is, or are you still trying to replace chars in the string as you're doing now? Who told you that this is something you can do?